Expression: sota, caballo y rey, context and word use
The expression "sota, caballo y rey" is derived from card playing. According to El Mundo, it means something that doesn't vary and is repeated in the same manner.

Por su parte, la expresión "sota, caballo y rey" se utiliza hoy en día para decir que algo apenas tiene variación o que se repite siempre del mismo modo.

So presumably it can be used for things like routines, "mi rutina diaria nunca cambia, es siempre la misma sota, caballo y rey".

Am I right with "la misma" and within this type of context?

El Mundo also states it can be used for a task that is easy to execute :

La locución también se suele emplear para expresar que algo es sencillo de ejecutar al no presentar dificultades: "Su trabajo no requiere ninguna habilidad ni conocimiento especial, es sota, caballo y rey".

In English,we may say, "this dish is so easy to cook, 5 minutes preparation, 10 minutes cooking time, BISH BASH BOSH".

Is it like that?

Es sota ,caballo y rey de preparar ese plato.
The RAE states:

m. coloq. Conjunto de los tres platos en que se considera dividido el cocido o la olla, y también la comida ordinaria compuesta de sopa, cocido y principio.

m. coloq. Conjunto fijo de cosas, que excluye o restringe la posibilidad de variación.


El Espanol also gives the example :

"La dieta de Juan es sota, caballo y rey".

So, I guess, I really want to know is it so flexible. Does this phrase make sense?:

Desde los tiempos de la María Castaña el flamenco sigue siendo lo mismo sota ,caballo y rey, con los mismos gestos, gritos y palmas expresando los sentimientos dolorosos.

This is an example sentence by the way,(not my real feelings)

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking exactly. Taking into account that the meaning of the expression is already explained correctly in El Mundo, I guess that you are only asking about the use in your examples.

Mi rutina diaria nunca cambia, es siempre la misma sota, caballo y rey.

For me this sentence is correct but it's lacking some separation between misma and sota.

Mi rutina diaria nunca cambia, es siempre la misma. Sota, caballo y rey.
Mi rutina diaria nunca cambia, es siempre la misma. Es sota, caballo y rey.

For me this sentence is not idiomatic

Es sota, caballo y rey de preparar ese plato.

Using your equivalent "BISH BASH BOSH", in non-idiomatic English, it would be something like

BISH BASH BOSH for the cooking is easy

For me it's more natural to have

Preparar ese plato es sota, caballo y rey. Cortar, cocer y sazonar y listo.

or

Ese plato es fácil de preparar
Ese plato es sota, caballo y rey, muy fácil de preparar

Note: Nature and position of "de preparar" deserves a separate question. Others will offer a good explanation.
And last but not least

Desde los tiempos de la María Castaña el flamenco sigue siendo lo mismo sota ,caballo y rey, con los mismos gestos, gritos y palmas expresando los sentimientos dolorosos.

It's almost correct. Not sure in the rest of Spain or in other Spanish-speaking countries, but here in Andalucía we say "de Mari Castaña". And if you say that something is sota, caballo y rey followed by samples, those samples should be brief. If the explanation is relatively long then it's not sota, caballo y rey

Desde los tiempos de Mari Castaña, el flamenco es sota, caballo y rey: quejíos, palmas y zapateo. Siempre lo mismo.


That is an excellent answer. It clarifies a lot of things for me. The examples are very clear corrections which I hope to take on board.

@Bluelion7 Glad to help :-)
